# CUstyle thesis cover / CV education section

Tags: tikz-pgf

The [CUstyle](http://petr.olsak.net/custyle-e.html) thesis, developed by Petr Olšák, has a nice format (or at least I like it). While I am ok with LaTeX, doing that kind of layout is beyond me.  I do, however, want to learn! Can you please teach me how to make these kind of cover? Note, I have my own style file that I use on a book document class.

Also, I would like to adapt it (ribbon and seal) for the education portion of my CV - a mockup included below.
Thoughts?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that wasn't useful. The video minimally to do with this question and focuses mostly on basic LaTeX, like making fonts bold, organizing chapters, etc.

Comment: I linked to it as the work was done at Petr Olšák's institution specifically to make a latex thesis class as an alternative to the opmac setup I'd have linked to the class but can't remember what it was called:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what you are saying is true - but it is about **making** a thesis, not about formatting graphics. Those are automatically done by their style file.

Comment: @yo' is quite active here I expect he'll comment later:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, Petr Olšák is also active under the username **wipet**. I haven't been working with `ctustyle` not `custyle`, but I'll fix some answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could be a good starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\ribbon{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-1.75,0) rectangle (1.75,0);
    \fill[color=red] (-0.5, 0.2) -| (0.5, -13) -- (0, -12.5) -- (-0.5, -13) -- cycle;
    \node at (0, -2) { \rule{2.5cm}{2.5cm} };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin3.5cm \itemindent0pt \labelsep0pt \labelwidth\leftmargin}
\item [\ribbon]\relax
\lipsum[5-7] % PUT YOUR FRONTPAGE MATERIAL HERE
\end{list}

% NOTE THAT 3.5cm = 2 * 1.75cm

\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. I am working on this now. I must say, however, I am also just learning tikz. Thus could you perhaps clarify both what -| means as well as how to replace the node with an image?

Comment: also, is there a way to generalize this to say a section? e.g. for the CV example then the ribbon length is as long as information related to that school? As for the cover it seems that that the ribbon and seal are slightly outside the margins?

Comment: Generalizing to a section -- what exactly do you mean? As for the first one, replace `\rule{2.5cm}{2.5cm}` by `\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{stamp.pdf}`.

Comment: thank you for the assist with the graphics ( I didn't think it would be that easy).  What I mean by generalize is that like in my mock-up there is a block of text specific to the seal + ribbon. So while what you provide works great for the title page (although for me it doesn't compile there...) I want to have the ribbon length be proportional to the number of lines of the associated text. Similar to section environment that just happens to get this on the side

Comment: Also how can I 1.)  make sure that the ribbons don't overlap (hence the call of generalization) and 2.) have a black outline :)

Comment: black outline is easy: `\fill[color=red,draw=black]`. For the second question, one needs a MWE, that's a completely different matter, stretchable stuff, and I don't think I'm able to answer that at the moment in a good way.